# Does Spivak's definition of a local maximum only make sense over sets that include open intervals containing the local maximum?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definition, epsilon-delta

I have a question regarding Spivak's definition of a local maximum (or minimum). First, I'll give you his definition, along with a theorem that comes right after it. Then, I'll give my question.

Calculus, 3rd Ed. by Michael Spivak Chapter 11, Page 186:

> DEFINITION: Let $f$ be a function, and $A$ a set of numbers contained
> in the domain of $f$. A point $x$ in $A$ is a **local maximum
> [minimum] point** for $f$ on A if there is some $\delta > 0$ such that
> $x$ is a maximum [minimum] point for $f$ on $A\cap (x-\delta, x+\delta)$.
>
> THEOREM 2: If $f$ is defined on (a,b) and has a local maximum (or minimum) at $x$, and $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f^\prime(x) = 0$

Ok, my question is, ***are we to assume that the set $A$ contains some open interval around $x$?***

Let's take the definition just as it's written:

For $f$ we'll use the function $f(x) = x$, which has as its domain $\mathbb{R}$, and is differentiable for all $x$ in this domain.

Define the set $A$ as

$A = \{x:0 \leq x \leq 1\} \cup \{7\}$

Using Spivak's definition, we have a function $f$, and a set of numbers $A$ that's contained in the domain of $f$. If we look at the point $x = 7$, and use $\delta = 10$, then $A\cap (x-\delta, x+\delta)$ is just $A$, right? $f(7) = 7$ is the maximum value of $f$ on $A$, so by THEOREM 2, $f^\prime(7) = 0$, which is obviously not true.

It seems like Spivak forgot to specify that $A$ must contain some interval containing $x$, but maybe I'm missing something simple?

In Theorem 2, when he says "If $f$ is defined on $(a,b)$ and has a local maximum at $x$," is he implying that $x$ is in $(a,b)$ and is the local maximum on $(a,b)$?

I'm not quite sure why he's bothering with the set $A$ at all. It seems like you could say the point $x$ is a local maximum if there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $x$ is a maximum point for $f$ on $(x-\delta, x+\delta)$, and leave it at that. Why bring $A$ into it? (Probably I'd find out in a few chapters, if not pages!)

I strongly suspect I'm being dumb and I'll regret asking this in about 5 minutes...

Comment: "If $f$ is defined on $(a,b)$", your $A$ is not an interval. It is still true that, in your example, that $f(7)=7$ is a local max as we can allow for general $A$ instead of only intervals for local max

Comment: Of course that isolated point is also a local minimum.

Comment: André Armatowski: Ah, so in THEOREM 2, $(a,b)$ is THE set? That makes more sense. I was reading it with minimal assumptions. In my defence, 1 page before all this, Spivak brags about how "precise" he's about to be! Thanks, André!

Comment: @Ben Yes, and even better, we can allow for $f$ to be defined on some larger set like $[a,b]$ or in general $(a,b)\cup B$ for some $B\subset \mathbb{R}$. The theorem holds as long as the maximum $f(x)$ occurs at some $x$ in an open interval that belongs to the domain of $f$ (and $f$ is differentiable at $x$ of course). As a side; I like your choice of book, I would probably not have pursued a bachelors in mathematics had I not read it.

Comment: Would this be correct revision of THEOREM 2?  "If $f$ is defined on $(a,b)$ and has a local maximum (or minimum) **on $(a,b)$** at $x$, and $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f^\prime(x) = 0$

Comment: @Ben Indeed, and it is what Spivak means.

Comment: @André I'm loving the book, occasional mistakes and hiccups notwithstanding. Thanks so much for your help! It's much clearer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does Spivak's definition of a local maximum only make sense over sets that include open intervals containing the local maximum?

No.

The definition works for arbitrary sets of numbers that are contained in the domain of $f$.

In my example, there are 2 local maximums on $A$: $x = 1$ and $x = 7$.
There are 2 local minimums: $x = 0$ and $x = 7$.

However, Theorem 2 doesn't apply to any of these points. Theorem 2 applies to a point that is a local maximum [minimum] over an open interval containing that point. We can form an open interval within $A$, but it won't contain any of $A$'s local maximums or minimums.

Theorem 2 can be made less ambiguous with a minor edit:

**Theorem 2, revised:** *If $f$ is defined on (a,b) and has a local maximum (or minimum) **on** $\bf{(a,b)}$ at $x$, and $f$ is differentiable at $x$, then $f^\prime(x) = 0$*

If we do have a point $x_m$ that's a local maximum on an interval $(a,b)$, this means via the definition that there is some $\delta > 0$ such that $x_m$ is a maximum point on the intersection $(a,b) \cap (x_m-\delta, x_m + \delta)$.

Given 2 open intervals that contain the same point, it's easy to show their intersection will be an open interval containing that point. Our local maximum will be a maximum over this new interval.

If $f$ is differentiable at $x_m$, we can show that the limits from above and below force $f^\prime(x_m) = 0$.

(For example, if we define a new $\delta_2 = \min(x_m-a, b-x_m, \delta)$, then $x_m$ will be a maximum point on $(x_m-\delta_2, x_m + \delta_2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Theorem 2 has three hypotheses.

- $f$ is defined on $(a,b)$ and
- has a local maximum (or minimum) at $x$, and
- $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

For your example with $f(x) = x$ with domain $A = [0,1] \cup \{7\}$, and $\delta = 10$,

- $f$ is not defined on $(7 - \delta, 7 + \delta)$ or on any other open interval containing $7$.
- $f$ has a local maximum, local minimum, and global (sometimes called "absolute") maximum at $7$.
- $f$ is not differentiable at $7$.

So all three hypotheses fail to apply to this $f$ at $7$.  Therefore, we can neither confirm nor deny the consequent: "$f'(7) = 0$".  (And, this is good; that derivative does not exist.)

Comment: Hi Eric, I think that in my example, $A$ is not the domain. $A$ is a set contained in the domain (as specified in Spivak's DEFINITION). My confusion seems to be rooted in his sort of glancing over the fact that in THEOREM 2, $(a,b)$ is the set on which $f$ has its local maximum.

Comment: Thank you though Eric. I think I understand what Spivak is saying a bit better now.